# Monitor - HP ZR2740W 27" - Resolution 2560 x 1440 can't be set

Tags: display, resolution

**My problem**

I just bought a computer screen which has a maximum resolution of 2560 x 1440. I have a PC and it only show me the choices for the resolution 1680 width and below. I already installed the drivers.

**My question(s)**

Can the resolution choice depend on what graphics card I have installed? Maybe I need to

- change my graphics card?
- Is resolution 2560 x 1440 just for Mac and not for PC? I hope not.
- Am I in the right Q&A for this question?

***What do I have to do?***

Comment: Yes, the resolution depends on the video adapter. Have you looked up the specs of your video card to see if it supports that resolution?  Or perhaps (at least) provide us with the make and model, so we can give you an informed answer... :)  Also, what connection type are you using (VGA, DVI, HDMI)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a DVI cable. When changing to display port it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Resolutions above 'HD' (1920x1080 or 1920x1200) require you use a 'Dual Link' DVI cable.  If the cable you had was single link (google those terms to find out how to ID the cable) then it will limit the resolution, or look like hell.

You need to (as you did) use a displayport cable if your monitor supports that, or get a Dual Link DVI cable  (would be surprised if the monitor did not come with one)

Note also that if you are connecting to something like a Mac, using their mini-display port or `thunderbolt` connector, that most of the cheap passive mini display port to DVI adaptors are Single Link, and thus will not work at the higher resolutions.  You can get mini-dp to DualLink DVI adaptors, but they are not cheap, ones from places like Monoprice.com run for around $50, and the official Apple one is likely close to double that.   If the monitor supports displayport, just get a mini to regular DP cable, it will be a lot cheaper.  The only reason to go with a mini-DP to DualLinkDVI adaptor would be if the monitor does not have displayport, or you are doing something like feeding a DVI KVM (Keyboard, Video, Mouse) switch to serve two systems with a single display. (in which case it better be a good KVM that supports Dual Link DVI

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the exact same boat. I also have the HP ZR2740w and it comes with a DP and DVI-D Dual Link cables.  I can get 2560x1440 using the DP cable with my UltraBook but I have been unable to get that resolution using DVI with any of my desktops.  I've tried Sandy Bridge and Ivy Bridge based IGP's and a Radeon 7750.   I've tried creating custom display profiles using the Intel drivers with no luck.  Perhaps the motherboards are fake dual link ports and are only single link DVI.

I can't imagine that the DL ports on a Radeon 7750 are incapable of 2560x1440.  The catalyst drivers don't allow creating custom resolutions but there seem to be some registry hacks and custom utilities out there to do it.  I've tried, but still no luck.

My last remaining option is to find a mini DP to DP cable and use that on my Radeon 7750.  Either that or go get another graphics card with a full size DP port.

So my "answer" if you will is to forget about DVI and use DP.  But this seems wrong and broken to me because why else would they bother putting DVI and DP ports and provide cables with this monitor?  Surely there must be some alignment of the stars where DVI actually works.

I'll keep trying and update my answer if I ever find it.

Comment: For anyone coming across this now..  DVI being the older standard is on the way out.  However if you have an older monitor it may not support HDMI or DisplayPort (which are newer standards).   To go above HD resolution, DVI requires using what is called 'dual link' (addressed in my answer above) and adapters that go from mini-DP/Thunderbolt to Dual-Link DVI usually require a power input and are more expensive.  Expect a cheap Mini-DP to DVI adaptor to be limited to 1920x1280.  If the monitor supports DP, that's by far the easier option.

Comment: As I recall, I got this monitor to work using an AMD R7-260x. Can't remember if it was display port or DVI-D dual link.  As mentioned above this monitor is really stripped down and it works or it doesn't.  I've since moved on to dual 27" 4K IPS monitors that have HDMI and DP inputs that are drama free.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same monitor and have just found out that they are "direct drive", which means that the monitor has very limited resolution options, no on-screen display and has a limited set of behaviours.

https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c03277181

As this article states, if your video driver doesn't output the correct resolution, then you will go a no signal response.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the right place.

This sounds like you may have an inadequate video card that doesn't have enough RAM which is highly unlikely unless you're using a very old video card. Therefore, I'd be looking to upgrade/update the video card's drivers (I don't know what you have so you'll have to ask that in another thread).

If you're sure you have the best and most current drivers then you may want to adjust your driver settings to allow you to see all the resolutions that your card may support - not just the resolutions that your driver thinks your monitor is capable of. (I might be able to help there too if I knew what OS and card you had.)

Of course, the simplest thing might be to just get a better monitor cable. If you use VGA (which I don't recommend) and your VGA connection is only using 3 or 4 lines (connections) then it's almost a certainty that your card can't properly detect your monitor. This is almost always a problem when a KVM switch is used too. But if you're using a DVI cable then you should be OK. HDMI is also usually acceptable and able to provide monitor info back to the card although you may have troubles with audio.

So if you want to provide more info about your system maybe someone can help better. (Sorry if that's not much help.)

Comment: Good answer, a vote up for that. However it was not the right one for my problem. I was using a DVI cable when display port cable was required for the high resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I have this monitor, and have successfully displayed content at 2560x1440 content from Windows 10, Linux (Ubuntu 19 & Fedora 32) and OS-X. I have done so with an Nvidia Geforce 550 Ti, a 750 Ti, a Quadro M5000M and Intel HD Graphics 530 (i7 6820HQ).

As others have said, to properly display resolutions greater than 1080P, either display port or DVI must be used. If DVI is to be used, you must be using a source that supports *Dual Link* DVI, as well as a *Dual Link* DVI cable (if your DVI cable does not have 8 columns of pins / has a missing column of pins in the center, it is **not** a *Dual Link* cable). I have never had success using an HDMI to DVI cable, or an HDMI to DVI adapter (even with a *Dual Link* DVI cable) regardless of whether or not the source device was supposed to support QHD or 4K resolutions. If you only have an HDMI output available, an HDMI to DisplayPort adapter such as this [StarTech.com 4K 30Hz HDMI 1.4 to DisplayPort 1.2 Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0144NS4Z6) should allow you to connect an HDMI source to the DisplayPort input of the display. I cannot confirm personally that such an adapter will work, but I have no reason to believe that it would not, as long as the source device supports 2560x1440 / 1440p resolutions over HDMI.

I can confirm that the two GeForce cards mentioned above worked with both DisplayPort and DVI. As for the Quadro chip and Intel HD graphics; I can only confirm they will work with DisplayPort, as the two laptops with those graphics chips only have micro / mini DisplayPort, HDMI and VGA.

Answer (score 0):

Having 2 of these monitors I can confirm that troubleshooting this specific model is challenging.

I can also confirm that this monitor works with both DVI and DP at native resolution without issue. I Can even confirm that I was able to do this via HDMI-to-DVI adapter. Technically speaking first gen HDMI is a DVI signal standard, they differ only in the connector, so there is no HDMI-to-DVI adapter, there's just a cable with two different connectors at the end, when we talk about HDMI 1.0 and maybe one later revision.

But I can also confirm that I was unable to get output from HDMI in a laptop. But this is actually an HDMI implementation in early laptops, not anything with the setup. Specifically, even though my laptop came with discrete graphics card in addition to integrated Intel HD, there is a hardware limit on the resolution that can be outputted in that situation, which is FHD (1920x1080). In other words: Intel HD limits HDMI resolution to 1080p in older laptops, even for ones equipped with second, more powerful graphics card.

FYI.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this monitor for years and tried with my wife's laptop and it still only gives 720p from HDMI (to dual link DVI) to this monitor.  I have tried with my laptop and both of our laptops will show 1440p on my main monitor but this HP will never go above 720p using HDMI.  So frustrating.  My wife's laptop is no more than 2 years old.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).