# Unable to get higher resolution than 1280x720 with HDMI to DVI dual link

Tags: linux, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card

I am unable to get a higher resolution than 1280x720 when I connect my laptop with a second screen via an HDMI to DVI dual link connection. These are my specifics :

- operating system : Linux Mint 19.3, 64 bit
- laptop : HP ProBook 450 G6
- monitor to connect to : HP ZR2740w
- cable type : HDMI (signal coming out from the laptop) to DVI-Dual link (signal to be displayed on monitor)
- video card details (displayed with **inxi -G**) :

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce MX130] driver: nvidia v: 440.82 
  Display: server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: modesetting,nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce MX130/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.82
```

Findings :

- the only possible resolution to choose from for the second screen is 1280x720
- I have tested the monitor with a PC with a DVI to DVI cable where it can provide a resolution from 2560x1440
- I know that HDMI to DVI-dual link can at least get up to 1920x1080
- I have installed the latest NVIDIA video card drivers
- Internal laptop resolution is 1920x1080
- I have tried both to extend the display (running two independent ones) and to use only the 2nd screen (showing content only on the 2nd screen) - in both cases the outcome is the same - maximum on external monitor is 1280x720

From my research I have come across a possible solution to use an HDMI to DisplayPort adapter (as the monitor has a DisplayPort as well), but I have not bought anything and I am not still 100% sure if it is a software or a hardware issue.

Has anyone faced similar issues and can provide tips on approaching this one ?

Comment: adapters don't always work well

Comment: What is the laptops internal screen resolution? Are you trying to mirror that or to use two independand displays. (Sorry, not sure about Mint's terminology. In windows it would be 'mirror' (both the same with the lowest shared resolution), 'extend' (both screen on independantly' or 'show on 2 only' (assuming the external monitor is the second screen).

Comment: If you were mirroring your display, you would max out on your laptops' display. If you extended your display, you should be able to go much higher. If you are extending your display, then I'd look at the cable next, if you have a spare around. If a different cable doesn't work, then I'd get into some settings on your machine. But what settings, I'm not sure at this point.

Comment: @Hennes I have updated the question - internal screen resolution is 1920x1080. I have tried both to mirror the display and to extend the display (running two independent ones) - in both cases unsuccessfully and I would be happy if either of both works (mirror OR extend).

Comment: The ZR2740w runs at a Native resolution of 2560x1440 and Safe resolutions of 640x480 or 1280x720.


OK. Good to see the question updated. A few notes:

1) Max DVI-D (normal DVI, sunch as also used on classic HDMI out) is max 1920x1200. Not enough for the monitors native 2560x1440.
2) Unverified: This is a direct driven display. So it only runs 2560x1440 or two fall back resolutions. One of those is your 1280x720.
3) Some link to also check: https://superuser.com/questions/437660/monitor-hp-zr2740w-27-resolution-2560-x-1440-cant-be-set

Comment: (more links which did not fit in the previous comment window:

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/Limited-Max-Resolution-1280-x-720-on-HP-ZR2740w-Monitor/td-p/6180870

https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c03277181.

Answer (score -1):

Use displayport on that monitor instead. I have not been able to get decent resolution using dual link DVI with that monitor.

My laptop does not have displayport output, however I am using docking station that has displayport output. Using displayport cable enables 2560 x 1440 resolution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).